# Gracenote php throwing HTTP RESPONSE ERROR

Tags: php, gracenote

I'm trying to get Gracenote APi to work on my site. I got it working some months back but never went any further. I am using the same credintials that used back then when it worked and the php gracnote class from Rich Adams on [github](https://github.com/richadams/php-gracenote). I am trying to get the example file to work but am recieving this error.

**Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'HTTP_RESPONSE_ERROR' in C:\wamp\www\Interface\php-gracenote-master\php-gracenote\HTTP.class.php on line 113**

This is on my localhost atm. I tried it on my server aswell and it threw the same error.

I have made another app on Gracenote thinking they may have blocked the old one but that didn't help. Does gracenote block the entire account if it isn't active for some months or I am I just been a tool and missing something here?

**EDIT**

The issue seems to be when trying to register for a user id

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when cURL returns an error code when trying to make the request to Gracenote's servers.

There was a bug in `php-gracenote` where `HTTP_RESPONSE_ERROR` wasn't defined, which is why you didn't get a human-friendly error message. I've just updated the code on GitHub, so you'll actually get a proper error now.

The exception will give you the cURL error code that was returned, which you can lookup in the [libcurl error codes](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) to see what the problem is. Could be anything from a DNS issue to an incorrect SSL version.

As far as I'm aware, Gracenote doesn't deactivate accounts for inactivity on the developer program. This may change in future though.

Comment: Thanks Rich. I'm now getting this error : exception: code=2003, message=cURL returned an error when trying to make the request., ext=60. I have added this the construct function curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); How do fix this properly?